# Greasemonkey code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am new to web development.

i am using greasemonkey firefox add-on to change the content of this url

https://moodle.itfac.mrt.ac.lk/login/index.php

i used the following userscript

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        moodle_login
// @namespace   http://hayageek.com
// @include     https://moodle.itfac.mrt.ac.lk/login/index.php
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
//allow pasting

alert("Hello World");

document.getElementById("page-header-wrapper").innerHTML="<h1>Moodle<h1/>";

//document.getElementByClassName("signuppanel").innerHTML="hhhh";

//document.getElementByTagName("div").innerHTML="";
```

the two commented lines are nort working. other lines work fine.

please help me to overcome this issue

thanks in advance :)

Comment: *not working* is NEVER a useful thing to say in a question for help.  You should always include any console errors.... and those console errors, in this case, should have led you right to the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get element in javascript other than id then you should use `"getElement(s)ByXXXX()"`. Notice change of "(s)".

So below line `//document.getElementByClassName("signuppanel").innerHTML="hhhh";` should be like this

If you used "signupppanel" class once then

```
var elemt = document.getElementsByClassName("signuppanel");
```

It will return an object and use it as below

```
elemt[0].innerHTML="hhhh";
```

and if this class is used multiple time then walk in loop as below

```
for (i = 0; i < elemt.length; i++) {
    elemt[i].innerHTML="hhhh";
}
```

And same method you can follow for "getElementsByTagName"